# How to format sql query to get month without leading 0

Tags: mysql

I am trying to format mysql queries to show months without the leading zero. I know `%m` will give me the month with the leading zero but I was wondering if there was anyway to get it without the leading 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%c` - Month, numeric (0..12)

(source: [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format))

```
Specifier   Description
%a  Abbreviated weekday name (Sun..Sat)
%b  Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)
%c  Month, numeric (0..12)
%D  Day of the month with English suffix (0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, …)
%d  Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
%e  Day of the month, numeric (0..31)
%f  Microseconds (000000..999999)
%H  Hour (00..23)
%h  Hour (01..12)
%I  Hour (01..12)
%i  Minutes, numeric (00..59)
%j  Day of year (001..366)
%k  Hour (0..23)
%l  Hour (1..12)
%M  Month name (January..December)
%m  Month, numeric (00..12)
%p  AM or PM
%r  Time, 12-hour (hh:mm:ss followed by AM or PM)
%S  Seconds (00..59)
%s  Seconds (00..59)
%T  Time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss)
%U  Week (00..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 0
%u  Week (00..53), where Monday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 1
%V  Week (01..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 2; used with %X
%v  Week (01..53), where Monday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 3; used with %x
%W  Weekday name (Sunday..Saturday)
%w  Day of the week (0=Sunday..6=Saturday)
%X  Year for the week where Sunday is the first day of the week, numeric, four digits; used with %V
%x  Year for the week, where Monday is the first day of the week, numeric, four digits; used with %v
%Y  Year, numeric, four digits
%y  Year, numeric (two digits)
%%  A literal “%” character
%x  x, for any “x” not listed above
```